# What should we do with Photoshop questions?

Tags: discussion, photoshop

We get a lot of questions about Photoshop or other image editors that [don't really relate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7486/photoshop-pen-tool) to Photography. The standard practice with these [seems to be](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/mist-photoshop-cs5-effect) to [close them](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop). This might provide resolution to our site, but not to the user who asked them in the first place.

It seems like a bad idea to leave perfectly good questions unanswered, even if they're off-topic. What should we do with questions like these?

Comment: @mattdm - thanks for the link but that doesn't answer the question at all ..  it actually makes it more complicated as it added a 3rd option to where these should go . .

Comment: Yeah that's why I put it as "see also", not an answer. I don't think we _have_ a solid answer yet.

Answer (score 9):

Migrate them to [the Graphic Design stackexchange site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), which is still in beta but has plenty of Photoshop questions.

Comment: The Graphic Design community is open to this, assuming they are not basic "how do i use this program" questions: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions

Comment: Also see http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-this-se-site-include-technical-questions-ie-photoshop-etc/

Answer (score 4):

Migrate them to superuser, which has [34 pages of questions about photoshop](https://superuser.com/search?q=photoshop)

Comment: Wouldn't want to be the poor sap who has to move all 34 pages worth to Graphic Design @ SE later on. ;P

Comment: Just because they already have 20 pages (of 50 each) mentioning Photoshop, doesn't mean it's the right place to get a good answer...

Comment: @Rowland I think Graphic Design would be a better place for most PS questions, but some might be better off on SU.

Comment: I'm not really sure all photoshop questions belong on Graphic Design @ SE. I would say that any that are more related to how to use the program, vs. how to achieve a graphic design technique, would probably do just as well, or maybe better, on SuperUser. I guess its a judgment call at time of migration.

Answer (score 3):

There is the third option for borderline cases -- encourage the original question asker to clarify their question further -- sometimes they may be wanting to know how to use a tool with the intent of fixing a photo. By improving the question, and giving answers that guide a question to be more on topic; this way, a bad question can be rescued.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the questions about any photo manipulation software should remain here as log as it is about photography.

Photoshop, Lightroom, Aperture, Capture One .... is in our everyday workflow, it's the digital darkroom, it's Photography.

If someone asks how to slice his layout in photoshop for his new photography site, that should be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an issue that other photographers will encounter in their post processing, it belongs under the photography umbrella instead of bouncing around other SE sites.  For example, How do you dodge or burn in photoshop?.

Comment: Dodging and burning are photo-post-processing steps, so sure. But, to take it to an extreme, something like "How do I configure my mouse? I use a mouse in photoshop..." shouldn't be. In between, there's generally a gray area, but I think we should error on the side of focusing the site on photography and on _processes_, not on the user interfaces of particular pieces of software (even ones used in photography).