# Where is the right stackexchange site to post photoshop questions (here or superuser) ?

Tags: discussion, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should we do with Photoshop questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions)

i see that Photoshop questions both here and on superuser.com and i was wondering if there is  a clear place to put these questions as they seem to be dispersed?

I can see both points of view but i am just looking for a recommendation on where i should post my Photoshop questions?

Comment: See also [What should we do with Photoshop questions?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions)